# How to read complex txt file with blocks of data and save it as csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv, scrape

If i have a file organized like this

```
++++++++++++++
Country 1

**this sentence is not important.
**date 25.09.2017, also not important
*******
Address
**Office

        Address A, 100 City. Country X
**work time 09h00-16h00<br>9h00-14h00
**www.example.com
**emal@example.com;
**012/345 67 89
**téléfax 123/456 67 89
*******
Address
**Home Office

        Address A, 200 City. Country X
**email2@example.com;
**001/000 00 00
**téléfax 111/111 11 11
*******
Address
**Living address

        Address 0, 123 City
**info@example.ch
**000/000 00 00
**téléfax 222/222 22 22
++++++++++++++
Country 2

**this sentence is not important.
**date 25.09.2017, also not important
*******
Address
**Office

        AAA 11, 30 City 

        BBB 22, 30 City
**work time 08h00-12h30  
**www.example.com
**info@example.com
**000/000 00 00
**téléfax 111/11 11 11
*******

ETC
```

And i want to put data in csv file with these columns:

```
Country (Line right after ++++++++++++++), Address (Line right after *******), Office (after **), WorkTime (after **), Website (after **), Email (after **), Phone (after **), Fax (after **)
```

How do I do it in Python? Problem is, in some lists there is missing data, so i know some rows in csv file will end up all messed up, but i don't mind doing some manual work tweaking the database after i do this. Another problem is, country names vary, so i would need to use ++++++++++++++ as separator.

I tried something like this

```
import csv
with open('listofdata.txt', 'r') as FILE:
   DATA = FILE.read()

LIST = DATA.split('++++++++++++++')

LIST2 = []
LIST3 = []
LIST4 = []

for ITEMS in LIST:
    LIST2 = ITEMS.split('*******')    
    for items2 in LIST2:
        LIST3 = items2.split('**')
        LIST4.append(LIST3)


with open('file.csv', 'w') as CSV:
    for ITEMS in LIST4:
        csv.write(ITEMS)
```

But it doesn't work.

ERROR: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in 
    csv.write(ITEMS)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write'

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the very last line you wrote your file object "csv" instead of "CSV", that was the reason there was an error.

I added the procedure on how to use the csv module within python to your code.

All you have to do now is work on your parsing method.

Code:

```
import csv
with open('listofdata.txt', 'r') as FILE:
   DATA = FILE.read()

LIST = DATA.split('++++++++++++++')

LIST2 = []
LIST3 = []
LIST4 = []

for ITEMS in LIST:
    LIST2 = ITEMS.split('*******')
    for items2 in LIST2:
        LIST3 = items2.split('**')
        LIST4.append(LIST3)

with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for ITEMS in LIST4:
        spamwriter.writerow(ITEMS)
```

Output:

```
""

"
Country 1

","this sentence is not important.
","date 25.09.2017, also not important
"

"
Address
","Office

        Address A, 100 City. Country X
","work time 09h00-16h00<br>9h00-14h00
","www.example.com
","emal@example.com;
","012/345 67 89
","téléfax 123/456 67 89
"

"
Address
","Home Office

        Address A, 200 City. Country X
","email2@example.com;
","001/000 00 00
","téléfax 111/111 11 11
"

"
Address
","Living address

        Address 0, 123 City
","info@example.ch
","000/000 00 00
","téléfax 222/222 22 22
"

"
Country 2

","this sentence is not important.
","date 25.09.2017, also not important
"

"
Address
","Office

        AAA 11, 30 City

        BBB 22, 30 City
","work time 08h00-12h30
","www.example.com
","info@example.com
","000/000 00 00
","téléfax 111/11 11 11
"

"
"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Now only to figure out how to write that csv using that rule from above: Country, Address, Office, Worktime, Website, Email, Phone, Fax.

Answer (score 0):

When you save to csv file use [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). But first you must prepare parser for structure of your `listofdata.txt` file and then you can save data to csv file.

Alternatively, you can use [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) but you must prepare parser first anyway.